# Zapier Code (JS) + Twitter API - POST statuses/retweet/:id

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, zapier

This JS code for Zapier by @ReganStarr enables to  generate a **"like"** action for any given `tweet_id` passed as a variable. I'm trying to modify it to generate a **"retweet"** action.

```
var twitterApplicationConsumerKey = 'MyTwitterConsumerKey';
var twitterApplicationConsumerSecret = 'MyTwitterConsumerSecret';
var twitterApplicationAccessToken = 'MyTwitterAccessToken';
var twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret = 'MyTwitterTokenSecret'; 

// That's it. No need to edit anything below.

function b64_hmac_sha1(k,d,_p,_z){
  if(!_p){_p='=';}if(!_z){_z=8;}function _f(t,b,c,d){if(t<20){return(b&c)|((~b)&d);}if(t<40){return b^c^d;}if(t<60){return(b&c)|(b&d)|(c&d);}return b^c^d;}function _k(t){return(t<20)?1518500249:(t<40)?1859775393:(t<60)?-1894007588:-899497514;}function _s(x,y){var l=(x&0xFFFF)+(y&0xFFFF),m=(x>>16)+(y>>16)+(l>>16);return(m<<16)|(l&0xFFFF);}function _r(n,c){return(n<<c)|(n>>>(32-c));}function _c(x,l){x[l>>5]|=0x80<<(24-l%32);x[((l+64>>9)<<4)+15]=l;var w=[80],a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,e=-1009589776;for(var i=0;i<x.length;i+=16){var o=a,p=b,q=c,r=d,s=e;for(var j=0;j<80;j++){if(j<16){w[j]=x[i+j];}else{w[j]=_r(w[j-3]^w[j-8]^w[j-14]^w[j-16],1);}var t=_s(_s(_r(a,5),_f(j,b,c,d)),_s(_s(e,w[j]),_k(j)));e=d;d=c;c=_r(b,30);b=a;a=t;}a=_s(a,o);b=_s(b,p);c=_s(c,q);d=_s(d,r);e=_s(e,s);}return[a,b,c,d,e];}function _b(s){var b=[],m=(1<<_z)-1;for(var i=0;i<s.length*_z;i+=_z){b[i>>5]|=(s.charCodeAt(i/8)&m)<<(32-_z-i%32);}return b;}function _h(k,d){var b=_b(k);if(b.length>16){b=_c(b,k.length*_z);}var p=[16],o=[16];for(var i=0;i<16;i++){p[i]=b[i]^0x36363636;o[i]=b[i]^0x5C5C5C5C;}var h=_c(p.concat(_b(d)),512+d.length*_z);return _c(o.concat(h),512+160);}function _n(b){var t="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",s='';for(var i=0;i<b.length*4;i+=3){var r=(((b[i>>2]>>8*(3-i%4))&0xFF)<<16)|(((b[i+1>>2]>>8*(3-(i+1)%4))&0xFF)<<8)|((b[i+2>>2]>>8*(3-(i+2)%4))&0xFF);for(var j=0;j<4;j++){if(i*8+j*6>b.length*32){s+=_p;}else{s+=t.charAt((r>>6*(3-j))&0x3F);}}}return s;}function _x(k,d){return _n(_h(k,d));}return _x(k,d);
}

var tweetId = input.tweet_id;

//create nonce
function generateRandomString(desiredLengthOfRandomString) {
    var result = '';
    var possibleCharactersForRandomString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < desiredLengthOfRandomString; i++ )
        result += possibleCharactersForRandomString.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleCharactersForRandomString.length));

    return result;
}

var randomString = generateRandomString(32);
var nonce = new Buffer(randomString).toString('base64');


//create timestamp
var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

//create the signature
var signatureParameterString = 'id=' + tweetId + '&oauth_consumer_key=' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '&oauth_nonce=' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' + timestamp + '&oauth_token=' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '&oauth_version=1.0';

var signatureBaseString = 'POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ffavorites%2Fcreate.json&' + encodeURIComponent(signatureParameterString);

var signingKey = encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationConsumerSecret) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret);

var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(signingKey, signatureBaseString);

var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json?id=' + tweetId;

var oauthString = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '", oauth_nonce="' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '", oauth_signature="' + encodeURIComponent(signature) + '", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="' + timestamp + '", oauth_token="' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '", oauth_version="1.0"';

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': oauthString
  }
})
.then(function(res) {
  return res.json();
})
.then(function(body) {
  var output = body;
  callback(null, output);
})
.catch(callback);
```

I thought that by modifying this line:

```
var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json?id=' + tweetId;
```

to this:

```
var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/' + tweetId +'.json';
```

as instructed by Twitter [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-retweet-id.html), would be enough but it doesn't work :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the endpoint mentioned on Twitter is different than the one you've changed it to. Could you try changing the `apiUrl` to the following?

`var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/' + tweetId +'.json';`

or (for better readability)

`` var apiUrl = `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/${tweetId}.json`; ``

I haven't tested this but it looks like the cause of the issue. Please also post the error you get in case this fails.

**UPDATE:**

The `SignatureBaseString` and the `SignatureParameterString` need to be changed as well.

```js
var twitterApplicationConsumerKey = 'MyTwitterConsumerKey';
var twitterApplicationConsumerSecret = 'MyTwitterConsumerSecret';
var twitterApplicationAccessToken = 'MyTwitterAccessToken';
var twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret = 'MyTwitterTokenSecret'; 

// That's it. No need to edit anything below.

function b64_hmac_sha1(k,d,_p,_z){
  if(!_p){_p='=';}if(!_z){_z=8;}function _f(t,b,c,d){if(t<20){return(b&c)|((~b)&d);}if(t<40){return b^c^d;}if(t<60){return(b&c)|(b&d)|(c&d);}return b^c^d;}function _k(t){return(t<20)?1518500249:(t<40)?1859775393:(t<60)?-1894007588:-899497514;}function _s(x,y){var l=(x&0xFFFF)+(y&0xFFFF),m=(x>>16)+(y>>16)+(l>>16);return(m<<16)|(l&0xFFFF);}function _r(n,c){return(n<<c)|(n>>>(32-c));}function _c(x,l){x[l>>5]|=0x80<<(24-l%32);x[((l+64>>9)<<4)+15]=l;var w=[80],a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,e=-1009589776;for(var i=0;i<x.length;i+=16){var o=a,p=b,q=c,r=d,s=e;for(var j=0;j<80;j++){if(j<16){w[j]=x[i+j];}else{w[j]=_r(w[j-3]^w[j-8]^w[j-14]^w[j-16],1);}var t=_s(_s(_r(a,5),_f(j,b,c,d)),_s(_s(e,w[j]),_k(j)));e=d;d=c;c=_r(b,30);b=a;a=t;}a=_s(a,o);b=_s(b,p);c=_s(c,q);d=_s(d,r);e=_s(e,s);}return[a,b,c,d,e];}function _b(s){var b=[],m=(1<<_z)-1;for(var i=0;i<s.length*_z;i+=_z){b[i>>5]|=(s.charCodeAt(i/8)&m)<<(32-_z-i%32);}return b;}function _h(k,d){var b=_b(k);if(b.length>16){b=_c(b,k.length*_z);}var p=[16],o=[16];for(var i=0;i<16;i++){p[i]=b[i]^0x36363636;o[i]=b[i]^0x5C5C5C5C;}var h=_c(p.concat(_b(d)),512+d.length*_z);return _c(o.concat(h),512+160);}function _n(b){var t="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",s='';for(var i=0;i<b.length*4;i+=3){var r=(((b[i>>2]>>8*(3-i%4))&0xFF)<<16)|(((b[i+1>>2]>>8*(3-(i+1)%4))&0xFF)<<8)|((b[i+2>>2]>>8*(3-(i+2)%4))&0xFF);for(var j=0;j<4;j++){if(i*8+j*6>b.length*32){s+=_p;}else{s+=t.charAt((r>>6*(3-j))&0x3F);}}}return s;}function _x(k,d){return _n(_h(k,d));}return _x(k,d);
}

var tweetId = inputData.tweet_id;

//create nonce
function generateRandomString(desiredLengthOfRandomString) {
    var result = '';
    var possibleCharactersForRandomString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < desiredLengthOfRandomString; i++ )
        result += possibleCharactersForRandomString.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleCharactersForRandomString.length));

    return result;
}

var randomString = generateRandomString(32);
var nonce = new Buffer(randomString).toString('base64');


//create timestamp
var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

//create the signature
var signatureParameterString = 'oauth_consumer_key=' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '&oauth_nonce=' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' + timestamp + '&oauth_token=' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '&oauth_version=1.0';

var signatureBaseString = `POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fretweet%2F${tweetId}.json&` + encodeURIComponent(signatureParameterString);

var signingKey = encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationConsumerSecret) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret);

var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(signingKey, signatureBaseString);

// var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json?id=' + tweetId;

var apiUrl = `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/${tweetId}.json`;

var oauthString = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '", oauth_nonce="' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '", oauth_signature="' + encodeURIComponent(signature) + '", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="' + timestamp + '", oauth_token="' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '", oauth_version="1.0"';

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': oauthString
  }
})
.then(function(res) {
  return res.json();
})
.then(function(body) {
  var output = body;
  console.log(output);
  callback(null, output);
})
.catch(callback);
```

Comment: Strange... it gives back the message: **Could not authenticate you. Code 32**, yet the the oauth credentials are the same for the already working 'like' action.

could it be something involving this line: 

`var signatureBaseString = 'POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ffavorites%2Fcreate.json&' + encodeURIComponent(signatureParameterString);`

It appears to be the variable serving the credentials, bundled with a like request,  but i'm not sure?

Comment: @EladRatson You are right, this is an issue with the authentication method. The `SignatureBaseString` and the `SignatureParameterString` variables were to be chaged. I've updated my answer with the correct code. As usual, if this answer solved your problem, please upvote and mark it as correct. ([info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))